# No data is displaying in ListView in Fragment. It displays upon scroll

Tags: android

here is my first fragment...what is the problem here i have four fragment bt in this fragment data showing only when i schroll it..basically i have four tab in this activity reamainig three work fine .in first fragment i use web service

```
public class Home_Fr extends ListFragment {

    int a;
    int i=0;
    String[][] radioname;
    String[][] radio_id;
    String[][] radio_img;
    String[] catname;

    ListView lv;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View frag= inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fr, container, false);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String name = preferences.getString("categories_id", "");
        String[] cat_id=name.split("-");
        Log.d("ye id milli ya ni",cat_id[0]);

        radioname=new String[cat_id.length][3];
        radio_img=new String[cat_id.length][3];
        catname=new String[cat_id.length];
        radio_id=new String[cat_id.length][3];
        for(a=0;a<cat_id.length;a++)
        {
            getdata(cat_id[a], a);
        }


        lv= (ListView)frag.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        lv.setAdapter(new HomeFr_listAdepter(getActivity(), catname, radioname, radio_img, radio_id));

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);




    }


    private void getdata(String k, final int l) {

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.dirble.com/v2/category/"+k)
                .build();

        RadioListApi api = adapter.create(RadioListApi.class);
        api.getCategories_id(new Callback<List<RadioListModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final List<RadioListModel> list, Response response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                catname[l]=list.get(0).getName();
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                    ImageModel im = list.get(j).getImage();
                    radio_img[l][j] = im.getUrl();
                    radioname[l][j] = list.get(j).getName();
                    radio_id[l][j] = list.get(j).getId();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //you can handle the errors here
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You can call init the adapter in onCreate method with empty list and then in the success of your web service, you can notifydatasetchange.

Comment: Maybe try writing notifydatasetchange in your success method if your adapter isn't null

Comment: thank yashir ....it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add notifyDataSetChange in the success method of your service response.

Try writing notifyDataSetChange in your success method if your adapter isn't null.